# Page resets after javascript function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a simple html page for a project. 
I have a submission form.I use jquery to validate it (no sure if i'm doing ir right).
After the submission is validated,i want to save the user's details(name,password),in an array. The array is created when the script loads.

I added the function SubmitUser() to the onclick event,but when the function finishes,and adds the user,the page resets,and the variables are reset.

I wonder if someone could point out to me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Boris

Here's the script code:

```
var userArray = new Array();
var passArray = new Array();
var userNumber = 0;

//Adding rules for validation

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate({
    rules: {
    password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
        }
    }
    });
}); 

//Add a method to validate

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addMethod("username", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Field must contain only letters");
}); 

//The function in question

function SubmitUser()
{
    if($("#registerForm").valid())
    {
    var user = document.getElementById('username');
    userArray[userNumber] = user;
    userNumber++;
    alert('Registered');
}

//Function to switch between the different pages in the menu.
function toggle(id) {
    if(id=='LoginPage')
        {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('WelcomePage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('RegisterPage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('GamePage').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(id=='WelcomePage')
        {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('LoginPage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('RegisterPage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('GamePage').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(id=='RegisterPage')
        {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('WelcomePage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('LoginPage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('GamePage').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if(id=='GamePage')
        {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('WelcomePage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('RegisterPage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('LoginPage').style.display = 'none';
        }
    return false;           
}
```

Comment: Please show the form. Sounds like you are not returning false to stop the submission - also what version of jQuery are you using

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to override the form's natural submit behavior, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#registerForm').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // suppress natural submit behavior
    submitUser(); // your function
  });
});
```

And since you're already using jQuery, you can greatly simplify your toggle code. For each block like this:

```
 if(id=='WelcomePage')
    {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('LoginPage').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('RegisterPage').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('GamePage').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

...you can instead do this:

```
if( id === 'WelcomePage' ){
  $('#'+id).show();
  $('#LoginPage, #RegisterPage, #GamePage').hide();
}
```

Or even more generally, handle all your toggling cases with one line:

```
function toggle(id){
  $('#LoginPage, #RegisterPage, #GamePage, #WelcomePage')
    .hide()
    .filter('#'+id).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,you've helped me a great deal,And enlightened me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your onclick event (on your 'submit' button):

```
onclick="javascript:return SubmitFunction();"
```

OR in your form tag (For normal submit button):

```
onSubmit="javascript:return SubmitFunction();"
```

Make sure you are returning true or false in your function. if false is returned page won't reset/refresh.

Comment: The "javascript:" prefix is completely unnecessary in "onfoo" attribute values. It's interpreted as a statement label by the JavaScript interpreter, and it means nothing at all to the browser.

Comment: I use it in the examples I give to other dev's to make it more clear when explaining solutions. To remove it/or not is entirely up to the developer. But thanks for making that statement.

Answer (score 0):

When the page refreshes or changes, the JavaScript variables are reset... Thats the unfortunate truth. Make sure the function that the form is on returns false to stop it from changing the page - so SubmitUser() should look like:

```
function SubmitUser()
{

if($("#registerForm").valid())
    {

        var user = document.getElementById('username');
        userArray[userNumber] = user;
        userNumber++;
        alert('Registered');


    }
return false;
}
```

Now, to change pages look at using jQuery.html ([Link](http://api.jquery.com/html/)) to load content in without actually changing the page (or jQuery.load ([Link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) to load an actual file, like games.html):